# SQL change value

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to do a select query where I'm trying to change the value.

```
select * from config where category = 'basic'
```

For example I would like that the output shows **'general'** instead of **'basic'**. But I don't want to update all the **'basic'** value's into **'general'**

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, ...,
  CASE 
    WHEN category = 'basic' THEN 'general'
    ELSE category
  END
FROM config
```

or, in this particular case:

```
SELECT field1, field2, ...., 'general'
FROM config
WHERE category = 'basic'
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of Case.. When statement resolve your issue

```
select 

  case when category = 'basic' then 'general' else category end

 from config
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.foo, c.bar, 'general' from config c where c.category = 'basic'
```